# set node as raft leader and leaseholder

Tags: performance, optimization, cockroachdb

I read on [cockroachdb docs](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/architecture/replication-layer.html) the following:

"*we can optimize query performance by making the same node both Raft leader and the Leaseholder*"

But how can you set a node to function both as raft leader and leaseholder (what commands)? Did I miss it in some manual?

Edit / extra background info:
I have a couple of nodes in one datacenter (low latency). But I would like to start a node in a different datacenter (for safety). I don't want that node to function as a leader...

Answer (score 1):

CockroachDB automatically ensures that the raft leader and leaseholder are colocated. There isn't anything manual to be done.

Comment: And it is not possible to set a leader/leaseholder manually? Background: I have a couple of nodes in one datacenter. But I would like to start a node in a different datacenter (for safety). I don't want that node to function as a leader...

Comment: In CockroachDB 2.1 (scheduled to be released next week), you can use the `lease_preferences` field of the zone configuration to specify that certain replicas should be preferred as lease holders: https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/dev/configure-replication-zones.html

Comment: But that one remote replica doesn't give you much safety (you need a *majority* of replicas to be alive, so you'd still be down if the datacenter with two replicas went down). To survive a datacenter failure, you need 3 DCs with one replica each, not 2+1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and pointing out towards CockroachDB2.1. P.S. that remote replica will be used as 'realtime backup' (and not to keep the database functioning).